# How do I remove OpenJDK?

Tags: java, tomcat, openjdk

I had removed OpenJDK installed by default from Ubuntu Software Center.

Eclipse had been showing that Installed JRE is OpenJDK.

I wanted eclipse should be configured to jdk I already installed and configured.

After Removing installed JRE from eclipse and pointed to my JDK installed, When I run my Project I am facing an error that "Starting apache-tomcat-6.0.32 The specified JRE installation does not exist".

I had deployed application war at tomcat webapps and applicaion is running fine.

Also, My Core Java is executed fine by Eclipse.

Kindly provide some suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu, you can have multiple versions of Java installed in your system.

Currently, there are several implementations of Java with their respective JDK package.

- OpenJDK - `openjdk-6-jdk`
- Sun Java - `sun-java6-jdk`
- and others including IBM Java

You can choose between the versions that you want to use with Ubuntu using the following command.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Answer (score 0):

Hןת

try "export JAVA_HOME={your eclipse java folder}" and then in the same terminal session run tomcat: "startup.sh"

Answer (score 0):

I had configured RunConfigurations and Project setting in Eclipse. Now project is running appropriately in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a link to your new sun java. Just download the jdk from Oracle's website and set the path. I think this [link](http://manoharbhattarai.wordpress.com/2010/03/23/install-java-manually-in-ubuntu-linux/) might help you.